# Converting an ajax call to a fetch api call and pulling the information into a php function

Tags: php, ajax, fetch-api, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to convert an .ajax call to a fetch call. The ajax works but the fetch pulls a 500 error when I try to pull the data in my wordPress php file.

I'm fairly new to the fetch api and that is why I'm trying to learn it. I have looked at MDN, wordPress site on custom hooks and rest api, searched the web and searched stack overflow. All they talk about is ajax. I don't know if I'm using the wrong search phrase but I have been trying to figure this out for hours and frustrated.

```
//working ajax in js file
createLike() {
    $.ajax({
        url: `${universityData.root_url}/wp-json/university/v1/manageLike`,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'professorId' : 789},
        success: response => {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: response => {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

//my conversion to fetch
createLike() {
            const data = {
                'professorId' : 789,
            };
            fetch(`${universityData.root_url}/wp-json/university/v1/manageLike`, {
                headers: {
                    'X-WP-Nonce' : universityData.nonce,
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                method: 'POST', 
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            }).then(function(response){
                return response.json();
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(err => console.log(`error : ${err}`))
        },

//php file
function createLike($data) {
    $professor = sanatize_text_field($data['professorId']);
    wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_type' => 'like',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_title' => '3rd PHP Create Post Test',
        'meta_input' => array(
            'liked_professor_id' => $professor
        )
    ));
}

function universityLikeRoutes() {
register_rest_route('university/v1', 'manageLike', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'createLike',
));

}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'universityLikeRoutes');
```

my error

```
{code: "internal_server_error", message: "The site is experiencing technical difficulties.", data: {…}, additional_errors: Array(0)}
additional_errors: []
code: "internal_server_error"
data: {status: 500}
message: "The site is experiencing technical difficulties."
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Well you set a `X-WP-Nonce` header in the fetch which you don't seem to be doing in the Ajax. Maybe something to do with that?

Comment: I did that because of my other fetch calls needed it but have since commented it out and it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The key is understanding what `$.ajax()` does differently than `fetch` and thus how you have to handle the data differently in wordpress.

`$.ajax` takes whatever you pass to the `data` option and converts into the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type by default. `$_POST` in PHP [automatically decodes indexed form variable names](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), which the `WP_REST_Request` object makes available to you within your callback as the `$data` argument.

`fetch` is different in several ways, you can read about this in several articles online, such as [this one](https://medium.com/@shahata/why-i-wont-be-using-fetch-api-in-my-apps-6900e6c6fe78). One thing you are doing differently is passing along a serialized JSON string and you are telling your endpoint that the data type is `application/json`. By design, the `wp-json` API doesn't by default parse this data for you. But you can access it nevertheless.

Instead of using `$data` as your callback argument, change it to a `WP_REST_Request` object. Then you can call the `get_json_params` method, and access whatever body you passed to the api that way.

For instance, change your `PHP` callback to the following:

```
function createLike( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $data = $request->get_json_params();
    $professor = sanitize_text_field( $data['professorId'] );
    wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_type' => 'like',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_title' => '3rd PHP Create Post Test',
        'meta_input' => array(
            'liked_professor_id' => $professor
        )
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank-you this works great!! FYI I realized I spelled sanitize wrong too.

Comment: I did but it won't show because my reputation isn't high enough yet.